# WPF DataBinding does not work with WPF DateTimePicker when input text is removed

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In WPF DataTimePicker, user can set Date either by clicking Calender besides it or entering input text.

So whenever I use one of above case, setter of property(which is binded to SelectedDate dependency property of DateTimePicker) gets called.

However, when I delete input text from datetimepicker manually, setter of binded property doesn't call.

So could any one help me in this regards? how  to call setter of the binded property, when input text manually removed from  WPF datetimepicker.

Comment: you should post some of your code... and try UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in your binding

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean DatePicker?

You can simply bind to a DateTime? property:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding MyDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />

private DateTime? _myDate;
public DateTime? MyDate
{
    get { return _myDate; }
    set { _myDate = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyDate"); }
}
```

Comment: Yes I mean DatePicker. And I already have above code implemented. Actually when I remove/delete input text from the datepicker control, I get "Value " could not be converted". I know that since property which is binded is of DateTime type and empty string cann't be converted to Datetime. So are there any solution to fix this problem?

Comment: it works for me, you have to use nullable datetime instead of datetime --> DateTime? or Nullable<DateTime>